# How do i add several functions into one command?

Tags: java, android

I have a dialog window with an EditText input field. I want to use the input value a few more times but want as less code as possible. At the moment i have to set up my alertdialogBuilder new for every Button click , but this is not very felxible.

I use that code for my alertDialogBuilder

```
public static void makeEditTextInputDialog(String caption, final Context mContext){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View inputDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_input_edittext, null);

   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setView(inputDialogView);

        final EditText etInput = (EditText) inputDialogView.findViewById(R.id.et_inputdialog);
        final TextView tvCaption = (TextView) inputDialogView.findViewById(R.id.tv_inputdialog_caption);

        tvCaption.setText(caption);

        builder .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.apply, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

how do i need to set up my class or function so that i can make a function where i can add more functions with a dot like

:`makeInputDialog(caption,context).newFunction(param).changeTheTextOfAnotherTextView(desiredTextView);`

Comment: Builder Pattern ==> http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternBuilder/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that by making your methods each return `this` as an instance of the Builder class that you are creating. That way you can chain the calls together with '.'

Here is a simple example:

```
class MessageBuilder {
    String address = "unknown";
    String state = "unknown";
    String country = "unknown";

    MessageBuilder() {}


    String show() {
        return address + ", " + state + ", " + country;
    }

    MessageBuilder setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
        return this;
    }

    MessageBuilder setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
        return this;
    }

    MessageBuilder setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
        return this;
    }
}
```

You use this by chaining together the set methods:

```
    MessageBuilder builder = new MessageBuilder();
    String msg = builder.setState("CA").setAddress("123 Main St.").show();
    Log.d("MessageBuilder", msg);
```

... which produces this in the log:

```
09-24 14:25:16.254 {...}  D/MessageBuilder: 123 Main St., CA, unknown
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i searched for.